# How do I force Safari to save password for ALL websites?

Tags: macos, safari

Just seems safari can be picky with what website password gets saved. Like I can save my password for stackexchange but I can't do the same for macrumors.com.

I've looked at Safari preferences and nothing stands out. Can you please help? Thanks

Comment: I am not at my computer now. So I can only guess. Try looking into `~/Library/Application Support/Safari` It might be somewhere there and you may be able to edit it to make a new saved password. Backup though! I dont think it is possible to save the same pass for all sites.

Comment: I would say it depends a lot on how the website is coded, not just Safari.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases it is the website itself telling the browser to not save the passwords. There are a number of ways a web programmer can implement this and a number of ways to get around it.

I used to use a little JavaScript "bookmarklet" that tried to turn off any JavaScript on a website that told the browser to not save the password. It worked about a quarter of the time. Barely worth the trouble.

More recently I have moved to a 3rd party password manager (1Password) that will save the password for **any** website.

Editing a preference file is chancy and annoyingly "manual" but possible (EG worth looking into if it is possible) depending on how geeky you want to get. And checking for preferences that say not to remember a password for a specific site in Keychain or Safari itself is worth checking on. But my bet is on a website telling your browser not to remember passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Safari Preferences on the Passwords tab, is macrumors.com there with something like “Never remember password”?  If so, you can remove that entry and try again.  You might also like to search for sites in Keychain Access.app as I think ‘never remember’ sites might get stored there as well?